# Не выходит получить ссылку на RecyclerView через ViewPager

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть фрагмент, который создает `View` из разметки с `RecyclerView`:

Фрагмент:

```
public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/table_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Я получаю три экземпляра этого фрагмента для `ViewPager` через его адаптер.

Адаптер:

```
private class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagesFragment page;

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        page = new PagesFragment();
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
```

Создание `ViewPager`:

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_viewPager_1);
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

После создания `ViewPager` я пытаюсь получить ссылки на `RecyclerView` из каждого фрагмента:

```
recycler_1 = pagerAdapter.getItem(0).getView().findViewById(R.id.table_recyclerView);
recycler_2 = pagerAdapter.getItem(1).getView().findViewById(R.id.table_recyclerView);
recycler_3 = pagerAdapter.getItem(2).getView().findViewById(R.id.table_recyclerView);
```

Но получаю NPE. Вот stacktrace:

```
11-29 19:33:08.723  25789-25789/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary/com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dugin_rostislav.dictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:216)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Вопрос: почему выбивает NPE, если фрагменты уже создали `View` и как получить `RecyclerView` из фрагментов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ошибаетесь. Те фрагменты, которые вы получаете из метода никаких втю не создали, т.к. вы из метода возвращаете новые экземпляры, в активити не добавленные.

Вам надо действовать так:

1. Создать список для фрагментов в адаптере.
2. Заполнить его в конструкторе адаптера экземплярами фрагментов.
3. Возвращать из getItem фрагменты из списка адаптера.
4. Быть готовым к неочевидному поведению такого подхода после поворотов экрана и т.п.

Так что я бы как-нибудь бы переделал... Как - не знаю)

Comment: А `RecyclerView`-то как получить?)

Comment: @bukashka101, ну... Также как вы пытаетесь сейчас... Возможно, раньше onResume не получится, т.к. им ещё и добавиться надо. И вообще - зачем вам они вне фрагмента?..

Comment: Добавлять я все буду из активности... Конечно можно попробовать методами в фрагменте, но разве меня не ждет тот же результат?

Comment: @bukashka101, я бы эту задачу решал так: берём либу `Otto` и посылаем из активити данные. Во фрагментах принимаем. Простое и изящное решение. И не надо прямого доступа к фрагментам из активити.

Comment: если вы сделаете как я предложил в ответе и фрагменты будете в onResume дёргать, то должно работать.

Comment: А что такое "либа `Otto`?

Comment: @bukashka101, сие тайна великая есть... Но, говорят, что есть один мудрец, который это знает... Гугл его зовут...

Comment: Мне страшно. Ни одного результата на русском О-О.

Comment: @bukashka101, качайте англо-саксонский)

Comment: @bukashka101 [Square Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) , но я предпочитаю [Greenrobot EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Если вам говорят о библиотеке - искать ее надо не в каком то результате на русском, а в наиболее очевидном месте - на *Github*

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, @pavlofff, я пытался понять, для чего вообще нужны `EventBus'ы`, но я, вместе с переводчиком, не смогли победить англо-саксонские туториалы, в следствии чего — я ничего не понял! Можете вкратце объяснить, для чего нужны `EventBus'ы`?

Comment: @bukashka101, например для того, чтобы активити могло вызвать метод к-л фрагмента во `ViewPager` без необходимости искать его в `FragmentManager`. Ещё, по идее, можно сервис дергать (его методы) из активити таким образом. Но на счёт сервиса я не уверен.

Comment: @bukashka101, вообще - задавайте вопрос тут - думаю, он будет полезен. Главное заголовок хороший написать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а чем плох вариант сохранить ссылки на фрагменты и использовать их?

Comment: @bukashka101, а что произойдёт, с этими ссылками в случае поворота экрана? А если у вас в пейджере 100 фрагментов и вы, отображая 1 попытаетесь дёрнуть 100-ый? Вот система сообщений тем и хороша, что просто посылает сообщение и не заботится о том, есть ли у сообщения получатели.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у меня 3 фрагмента и они должны пересоздаваться, при повороте.

Comment: @bukashka101, получатели сообщений регистрируются в методах жизненного цикла фрагментов и вам не придётся их учитывать при сохранении ссылок на фрагменты.

Comment: @bukashka101, таки создайте вопрос если вам что-то непонятно.